# Node.js twitter stream api

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am learning node.js using nettutplus introduction series. In this series there is a lesson for creating node.js app using twitter stream api, the code shown in video is exactly the same as the code i have written, however it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
var https = require("https");
var options = {
host: 'stream.twitter.com',
path: '/1/statuses/filter.json?track=bieber',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + new Buffer("username:password").toString("base64")
}
};

var request = https.request(options, function(response){
var body = '';
response.on("data", function(chunk){
    var tweet = JSON.parse(chunk);
    console.log("Tweet: "+ tweet.text);
});

response.on("end", function(){
    console.log("Disconnected");
});
});

request.end();
```

The error is get is this

undefined:1

^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

```
at Object.parse (native)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\monk\Desktop\folder\node\twitter.js:14:20)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:736:14)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
at HTTPParser.parserOnBody [as onBody] (http.js:141:22)
```

I am using windows and cmd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you are using is for old twitter api version 1. Twitter recently launched new version of api 1.1 and discontinued the older version. New twitter api requires you to authenticate every request and there are some changes in the authentication mechanism you can read in twitter developer site. As for above error in script it is because you are trying to parse JSON.parse(chunk); where chunk is html and you are getting those error. 
Try updating your code for latest version of twitter api.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse a small chunk of response from the request, which may not be a valid JSON. The complete response is a valid JSON.

It is streaming JSON constantly, delimited by endlines. And you have to handle those. You have to wait for the endlines then parse the recieved data.
See an implentation [here](https://gist.github.com/ryanmcgrath/833401)